# Is there any cipher standard based on SHA-3, where it is not used as part of RFC2104?

Tags: encryption, aes, ctr, sha-3

I'm thinking about using a cipher, which uses AES CTR+SHA-3. My basic idea is this:

```
IV|AES-CTR(PLAINTEXT_SIZE|PLAINTEXT|SHA-3(KEY|PLAINTEXT_SIZE|PLAINTEXT))
```

So, basically, the encrypted data contains the following:

- IV for AES-CTR
- AES-CTR encrypted of the following:

  1. size of plaintext in 64-bit little endian encoding
  2. plaintext
  3. Keyed SHA-3 of 1. and 2.

Is there a standard/recommendation, which is like this? I don't want to design the system from scratch, as I certainly will make mistakes, so I'd like to follow some standard designed by experts.

I'd like to use SHA-3 in way I written (if possible), not like as RFC2104 uses it (`H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))`)

But, if SHA-3 is better if it is used in a Encrypt-then-MAC way, I'll accept it.

Comment: Search for "Encrypt then  MAC" and "MAC then Encrypt".  Yours is the latter which has some issues in addition to re-using the key.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: thanks for the note, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't conflating prefix-key-hash vs HMAC and the concepts of encrypt-then-mac vs mac-then-encrypt. It seems like you have some crossed wires.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: it's possible, I'm a beginner in cryptography. That's why I'd like to follow some standard. Basically, I'd like to have a cipher using AES-CTR+SHA-3, but SHA-3 isn't used in a HMAC-* way.

Comment: Look up KMAC. It's the way to use SHA-3 as a MAC. https://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-185

Comment: What is your goal here?  What is your motivation for using anything other than a standard AEAD scheme like NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 or AES-GCM?  If you really need to build something out of these two parts, you should generally reach for encrypt-then-MAC composition, and pay close attention to nonces—prefer message sequence numbers as the nonces.  SHA-3 as prefix-MAC is reasonable, but KMAC is preferable.  If you absolutely insist on encrypt-_and_-MAC rather than encrypt-_then_-MAC, then you should at least include the nonce in the input to the MAC.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: my motivation is exactly the opposite. I'd like to use a standard, as I've written in my question. The problem is that I don't know any, as SHA-3 is new. So it is hard to find a standard, which is based on it. But as it seems, KMAC fits my needs. I don't insist on a method encrypt/MAC. I've read that EtM is the best, so I'll use it.

Comment: If you're just building an application, and there's no existing protocol that serves your needs right now, then you should pick the AEAD scheme of reasonable security that is most expedient for your application—which requires saying a bit more about what your application is and what you're trying to do in it.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: i do this as a hobby project, nothing serious. Currently, I'm working on an archiver, and I'd like to add encryption into it. And I like SHA-3, as its output value is not its full state, so it doesn't need "hacks" that SHA-1/2 needs. And I like AES CTR, because it has random access for both encryption/decryption. That's why I choose these algorithms.

Comment: The random access for AES-CTR streams is a red herring: it tempts you to operate on a part of an AES-CTR message without having the entire message in front of you authenticated.  You should break your messages into bite-size (not byte-size) chunks so that a DoS attacker can't make you choke on a chunk bigger than you can chew, and _never_ operate on unauthenticated data.  Then you should arrange to provide random access to _chunks_, _e.g._ with [miscreant](https://github.com/miscreant/miscreant).  Also consider studying how Tarsnap and Tahoe-LAFS work.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: thanks for the advice! Yes, I'm breaking the stream into chunks, each chunk has its own MAC: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53586/how-should-the-length-field-be-handled-in-a-cipher. Thanks, I'll check out your recommendations!